# Why doesn't trunc() turn a float into an integer?

Tags: julia

When doing `trunc(3.5)`, it returns a float, `3.0`, why?

I know that you can do `trunc(Int64, 3.5)`, but isn't the purpose of `trunc` to convert a float into an integer? Why does it work this way?

Comment: What rule would you use to decide what should be the target type of `trunc` if it was not the same as the source type?

Comment: That trunc converts into integers

Comment: I will expand on the problem with what you propose in the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us focus on the case when you pass a `Float64` to `trunc` (the analysis can be similarly extended to other types). Take that the value you want to truncate is `x`.

First note that then `trunc` can always perform the truncation of `x` to the nearest integral value less or equal than it. So in short - this operation is always well defined, possible to perform, fast, and type stable.

If we wanted to return an integer we have a choice: do we want to be type stable.
In Julia the answer in Base is yes. But this would mean that you would have to return `BigInt` value for the operation to be always well defined. But probably when you do `trunc` you do not expect to get `BigInt` as it will be expensive.

The alternative would be to return some other integer type, but then you would have to throw an error if the float is too large, again - this is something that most likely you do not want to get.

Here is an example showing the issue:

```
julia> x = 1e300
1.0e300

julia> trunc(x)
1.0e300

julia> trunc(Int, x)
ERROR: InexactError: trunc(Int64, 1.0e300)
Stacktrace:
 [1] trunc(::Type{Int64}, ::Float64) at ./float.jl:703
 [2] top-level scope at REPL[35]:1

julia> trunc(BigInt, x)
1000000000000000052504760255204420248704468581108159154915854115511802457988908195786371375080447864043704443832883878176942523235360430575644792184786706982848387200926575803737830233794788090059368953234970799945081119038967640880074652742780142494579258788820056842838115669472196386865459400540160
```

So in summary - because floats can span much wider range of value than *normal* integers the only safe option is to return float by default.